# Angular - Validating the dropdown values in the html

Tags: angular

I have a Devextreme form in angular 8 application. If you see in the code below the first control in the form is dropdown list (dxSelectBox).
The dropdown has a onSelectionChanged event. Selecting an item in the dropdown triggers this event. As you can also see in the html, we are using

For E.g

```
min: selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Life Plan' && selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Essentials Plan' ? 0.1 : 0
```

What is the best practice for doing such checks in the UI. I would have more values to be checked in the future and the condition above could grow. Any suggestions please

Html

```
<dx-form #benefitForm [formData]="formBenefitData" [showValidationSummary]="true" [labelLocation]="'top'">
      <dxi-item dataField="productBenefitId"
                editorType="dxSelectBox"
                [editorOptions]="{ items: availableBenefitTypes, valueExpr: 'id', displayExpr: 'name',
                  onSelectionChanged: updateSelectedBenefitData }"
                [label]="{ text: 'Benefit Type', location: 'top' }">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required"
                             message="Please select an option for the benefit type"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item *ngIf="selectedBenefitData?.coverAmountRequired"
                dataField="coverAmount"
                editorType="dxNumberBox"
                [label]="{ text: 'Cover Amount', location: 'top' }"
                [editorOptions]="{ min: 1, max: quoteCoverBounds.lifeCoverUpper, format: { type: 'currency', precision: 0 } }">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Please enter the cover required"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item *ngIf="!selectedBenefitData?.coverAmountRequired"
                editorType="dxTextBox"
                [label]="{ text: 'Cover Amount', location: 'top' }"
                [editorOptions]="{ disabled: true, value: 'Not applicable' }">
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item dataField="monthlyPremium"
                editorType="dxNumberBox"
                [label]="{ text: 'Monthly premium', location: 'top' }"
                [editorOptions]="{
                min: selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Life Plan' && selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Essentials Plan' ? 0.1 : 0,
                max: quoteCoverBounds.monthlyPremiumUpper, format: { type: 'currency', precision: 2 } }">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Please enter the cover required"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>

      <dxi-item *ngIf="selectedBenefitData?.indexable"
                dataField="indexed"
                editorType="dxSwitch"
                [editorOptions]="{ switchedOnText: 'YES', switchedOffText: 'NO' }"
                [label]="{ text: 'Is Indexed' }">
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item *ngIf="selectedBenefitData?.guaranteeable"
                dataField="guaranteed"
                editorType="dxSwitch"
                [editorOptions]="{ switchedOnText: 'YES', switchedOffText: 'NO' }"
                [label]="{ text: 'Is Guaranteed' }">
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item dataField="productCoverTermId"
                editorType="dxSelectBox"
                [editorOptions]="{ items: staticData.coverTerms, valueExpr: 'id', displayExpr: 'term', onSelectionChanged: updateTermDescription }"
                [label]="{ text: 'Cover Term Type', location: 'top' }">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Please select an option for the premium term type"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item dataField="coverTermLength"
                editorType="dxNumberBox"
                [label]="{ text: 'Cover term length' }"
                *ngIf="showCoverTermLength"
                [editorOptions]="{ min: 1 }">
        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Please enter the monthly premium for cover"></dxi-validation-rule>
      </dxi-item>
      <dxi-item itemType="button"
                horizontalAlignment="left"
                [buttonOptions]="{ text: formBenefitData.id ? 'Update' : 'Add', type: 'success', useSubmitBehavior: true }"></dxi-item>
    </dx-form>
```

CS file

```
public selectedBenefitData: BenefitType = {
    id: 0, name: '', indexable: false,
    guaranteeable: false, coverAmountRequired: true
  };

      public updateSelectedBenefitData = e => {
    this.selectedBenefitData = <BenefitType>e.selectedItem;
    if (!chain(() => this.selectedBenefitData.coverAmountRequired)) {
      this.formBenefitData.coverAmount = undefined;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could extract these conditions to the .ts file so that it is easier to track them and your template remains *relatively* cleaner.

Comment: Could you give me a example please

Comment: For eg: `<div *ngIf="checkIsValid()"> ... </div>` and in your CS file `checkIsValid() { // check your conditions here and return true/false }`

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: And is it fine checking my name string in the TS. Is that a good way of doing it

Comment: Generally, no as change detection would trigger those methods to be called eveytime.

Comment: Then what is the appropriate way ?

Comment: @Tom I would create a property in .ts file and bind that property in template instead of the function call.

Comment: @Tom we can change that property inside a function from .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how you can consolidate complex conditions into a property and use those properties into template files.**

Code Example for .ts file:

```js
validationProperty: boolean | string | whatever type you need; 

functionToSetValidationProperty() {
  this.validationProperty = selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Life Plan' && selectedBenefitData?.name != 'Vitality Essentials Plan' ? 0.1 : 0;
}
```

You can call above function to update the validation property anytime from the .ts file.

Examples of this scenario can be:

- When you get the latest data from API, you can call this function to update validation.
- You can call this function on `ngOnInit`
- Any where you want.

Code Example based on your example in the `Question`:

```html
min: validationProperty
```

**Reason Why we need to use property instead of function:**

Because change detection would trigger those methods to be called eveytime. (Got from comment by @Nicholas K. That is why we should not use methods in templates.